Struggling with transparent image textures and Shaders
I'm attempting to create low-poly playstation style models and I've encountered a rough patch in my process.I'd appreciate any assistance as I can't find any resources to assist with the issue.
for this model, I am attempting to use a transparent texture to provide a more convincing effect but when I attempt to use my old node setup to achieve a flat cell shaded style look the texture loses its transparency. My question is, is there any way to achieve similar results for the shader without negating my transparent texture? My original node set up uses Color ramp and Multiply which seemingly makes the texture's transparent elements appear as white.
Included are photos of my usual node setup and the only node setup I could make that would respect the image texture's transparency. any help is much appreciated as I'm a beginner and I feel so far out of my depth!



Hello, it's hard to understand, maybe show a reference image of the real object, also an image of your object, maybe share your file?
